# when define my own keras layer occur a none tensor object

Tags: tensorflow, keras

here is my own layer code and the model can compile and predict fine, but when I use the model method model.fit(x,y) it turn out an error about none tensor error, and I can not find the reason

```
class CenterPointClassifierLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super(CenterPointClassifierLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # check input_shape
        if len(input_shape) != 2:
            raise 'input should be in 1 dimension'
            self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                          shape=(self.c, input_shape[1]),
                          initializer='uniform',
                          trainable=True)
        self.one = K.constant(np.ones((self.c, 1)))
        super(CenterPointClassifierLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        def elem_op(pre, x_input):
            x_shape = K.int_shape(x_input)
            e = K.reshape(x_input, (1, x_shape[0]))
            _x = K.dot(self.one, e)
            del_x = K.square(tf.subtract(self.kernel, _x))
            distance = K.sum(del_x, axis=1)
            _c = K.argmin(distance)
            _class = K.one_hot(_c, self.c)
            return _class
        y_pred = tf.scan(elem_op, x, initializer=K.one_hot(1, self.c))
        return y_pred

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        out_shape = (input_shape[0], self.c)
        return out_shape
```

and here is the error i got when use fit method:

File "\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 412, in square
    return gen_math_ops.square(x, name=name)

File "\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 2585, in square
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Square", x=x, name=name)

File "\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 509, in apply_op
    (input_name, err))

ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.

please help, how can i fix the error when fit!!!
I do not know where the x come from and got the none values, and why there a square op in tf

Comment: The error occurs in gradient computation. The code after (and including) `_c = K.argmin(distance)` is not differentiable.

Comment: but when i recode the layer using tensorflow the model can be trained, thought does not perform well, it indicated that it is not the problem of gradient, and in my opinion the argmin function is differentiable as it transfers the min gradient like the max function or min function in cnn pooling layer or maxout activation